# Can I use "to drip" instead of "that dripped"?

Tags: writing, to-infinitive

> A water clock had a container.
>
> The container was filled with water **that dripped** through the hole.

In the second sentence, can I use "to drip" instead of "that dripped"?

> The container was filled with water **to drip** through the hole.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I read *The container was filled with water to drip through the hole*, I would understand that the sentence was meant to say that the purpose of the filling the container with water is to make it possible for the container to drip through the hole, which is nonsensical, and I would be confused about what the writer was trying to say.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - That's not how I would read it.  How do you get that the container would be dripping through the hole?  It is, after all, *water to drip through the hole*.  "To" just means "for the purpose of".  If somebody said, "The warehouse is filled with flour to make bread", you wouldn't think that the warehouse is being made into bread.

Comment: @stangdon After reading your comment, I can read it the way you suggest. I'll admit that this reading didn't occur to me at first. (I had the same problem with a similar sentence before; iirc, it was *Give me a fork to eat* where the context was eating pizza.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> The container was filled with water to drip through the hole.

This means the container was filled with water, and the reason it was filled with water was so that it could drip through the hole.  We don't know if the container has water now, just that in the past it was filled and the reason why was presented.

> The container was filled with water that dripped through the hole.

This *could* mean that the container was filled with water and that it all dripped out of a hole.  But it could also have the first meaning above, especially if we are talking about the container in a historical context and we are not physically in front of the container.

Simple past can occasionally be used to refer a periodic event in general that "used to happen", but not a specific instance of that periodic event.  Past perfect makes it clear that we are referring to a single past event that is not happening now.

> The container was filled with water that had dripped through the hole.